# How do I get data from a database using a Java bean and Map?

Tags: java, dictionary

In web project ,we get data  from  database, we need to package them then use these data, which package way should I use , `Map` or `JavaBean` ? 
for short , this question is just the choice between `javabean` and `map` ,which one is better and WHY

Comment: what kind of data are getting from the DB ?
With a proper example (and less opinion phrased) the question may be reopened

Comment: @rjdkolb thank you very much if you care for

Comment: I think it may be impossible to reopen by me since I don't have enough points.
I suggest you ask another question. Try to stay away from asking the question as an opinion. (Better , best are opinion words.)
Show some 'real' data you have in the table with the column types (e.g. number, string etc)

Comment: @rjdkolb, it`s a opinion , not a real question, just  the choice between javabean and map ,which one is better and WHY

Comment: I did my best to keep the essence of your question, it's a heavy edit.

Answer (score 1):

MVC its Model View Controller

> V => View => It has view technologies like JSP, JSF etc.
>   M => Model => It basically has Plain Old Java Objects(POJO).

If you want to populate data from Controller to your view layer... go for POJO.

Refer following article to understand what is MVC?

[MVC Design Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm)

**Edited**

To get data from database I prefer to use JavaBean, But It's better if you use any `ORM framework` like `Hibernate`. `Hibernate` will take care of `CRUD` operations using Entities you don't have to manually write queries and set data to JavaBean.

Comment: @shimpi ,well thanks for your answer , but it`s not the point why I ask this question, all  I want to know is just the choice between javabean and map ,which one is better and WHY